# Laravel SPA with Sanctum and remember me returning 419 (CSRF Token Mismatch) after inactivity

Tags: laravel, csrf, laravel-sanctum

We are using Laravel Sanctum in a SPA with the "remember_me" option.
At this moment we have a session lifetime of `120` seconds.

When a user logs in, Laravel will set 3 cookies;

- `*_session`, will expire in 120 seconds
- `XSRF_TOKEN`, will expire in 120 seconds
- `remeber_*`, will expire in 5 years (forever)

Due to user inactivity, the `*_session` and `XSRF_TOKEN` will expire. When the SPA is still open, and the next request will be a `POST` request, the user will get an `419` response error (CSRF Token Mismatch). Even when the `remeber_*` cookie is still available.

At this moment we have two options in mind;

- Ping `GET` request every 120 seconds.
- When 419 returned, send a `GET` request and retry the `POST` request again.

We are wondering what will be the best solution to fix this?

Comment: I have the same problem, and I still haven't figured out how to fix it